# Python simple rock, paper, scissors game

Tags: python, new-operator

Hey so I'm a starting programmer and for school I had to make a simple rock, paper, scissors game (best out of 3) in python. My issue is with the score system, I get the two following errors:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Fabian\OneDrive\School\Python\Project stuff\RockPaperScissors\game.py", line 66, in <module>
    game1()
  File "c:\Users\Fabian\OneDrive\School\Python\Project stuff\RockPaperScissors\game.py", line 26, in game1
    score_com = score_com + 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'score_com' referenced before assignment
```

And this is the code I have thus far:

```
import random

#variables
rock = 1
paper = 2
scissors = 3

#empty score
score = 0
score_com = 0

#game info
print("Rules and how to play: ")
print("The game is best out of 3")
print("If you wanna choose rock type 1, if you wanna choose paper type 2 and if you wanna use scissors type 3")
print("Dont worry if you forget what number represents what choice, there will be a reminder before you input a number")

#how the game works
def game1():
    
    choice = input("Choose: rock, paper or scissors (1, 2 or 3)")
    if choice == "1":
        choice_com = random.randint(1, 3)
        print(choice_com)

        if choice_com == 1:
            print("Tie!")
        if choice_com == 2:
            print("You lost!")
            score_com = score_com + 1
        if choice_com == 3:
            print("You win!")
            score = score + 1

    elif choice == "2":
        choice_com = random.randint(1, 3)
        print(choice_com)

        if choice_com == 1:
            print("You win!")
        if choice_com == 2:
            print("Tie!")
            score_com = score_com + 1
        if choice_com == 3:
            print("You lost!")
            score = score + 1

    elif choice == "3":
        choice_com = random.randint(1, 3)
        print(choice_com)

        if choice_com == 1:
            print("You lost!")
            score_com = score_com + 1
        if choice_com == 2:
            print("You won!")
            score = score + 1
        if choice_com == 3:
            print("Tie!")   
            
    
#the order of how things are supposed to be displayed and a simple way of seeing the score count
start = input("Start? y/n")
if start == "y":
    game1()
    print("Score player 1: ")
    print(score)
    print("Score player 2: ")
    print(score_com)
    game1()
    print("Score player 1: ")
    print(score)
    print("Score player 2: ")
    print(score_com)
    if score == 2:
        print("Player 1 wins!")
        exit()
    if score_com == 2:
        print("Player 2 wins!") 
        exit()  
    game1()
    print("Score player 1: ")
    print(score)
    print("Score player 2: ")
    print(score_com)
    if score == 3:
        print("Player 1 wins!")
    if score_com == 3:
        print("Player 2 wins!")
    if score == 2:
        print("Player 1 wins!")
    if score_com == 2:
        print("Player 2 wins!")
```

The issue is probably a pretty simple fix but as I said I'm new to programming so I cant find a fix. Thanks in advance to anyone that helps me!

Comment: All of the suggested answers below will work, but beware that your function seems not to be semantically correct, at least for choice == "2". Furthermore the variables `rock`, `paper` and `scissors` seem to be unused, so you could leave them away or integrate them into your print statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple fix would be adding the following lines at the beginning of your function so that it uses the global variables

```py
def game1():
    global score
    global score_com

    ...
```

Or, you can have `game1` take both scores variable and return the updated one.

Answer (score 0):

Your function game1 is using a `local` score_com variable.
You should indicate inside the function that you want to use the global variable.

```
def game1():
    global score_com
```

or reference the global variable as argument

```
def game1(score_com=score_com):
   ...
```

The same with the variable `score`

Answer (score 0):

By default Python, assumes that any variable which is altered by a function is local to the function.  If you want to alter a global variable like score_com, you need to add a `global score_com` declaration in the function.  In this case, you're also updating `score`, so that needs to be declared too:

```python
def game1():
    global score, score_com
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone that responded!

I added global in front of the variables as shown below and this worked just fine.

```
def game1():
global score, score_com
```

I will keep all answers in mind next time I have a similar situation :D